# spatial join that works like select by location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-join

Using ArcGIS 10.2.1

I have two polygon feature classes.  The features in each are
identical, but they have different tables with no common attribute
(long story).  In each FC there are overlapping polygons.  If I do a
select by location, using "are identical...," all of the approriate
features are selected.

I'm trying to get the attributes from FC #1 into the identical
feature in FC#2.  I can select them easily enough but can't join them.
Any ideas?

Comment: I normally convert one of the Polygon layers to Centroid (feature to point) and then run the spatial join.

Comment: I thought about that, but many of the polys overlap, and many are irregularly shaped, so it would have been messy.  As I did it, the actual location of the centroid didn't matter, just the number itself.

Answer (score 2):

By identical I am assuming you mean the polygons have the exact same geometry. If so just right click on one of the layers (polygon layer A) and select join.  You will be doing a join based on spatial location.  Select the layer you want to join to this (polygon layer B)  You will be joining Polygons to Polygons and select  the option to give each polygon the attributes of the polygon it falls completely inside. Then run the tool and the new table will have both fields.

Alternatively you could run from the toolbox the Spatial Join tool.  The Target Feature is Polygon layer A the Join is Polygon layer B, you will be joining one to one, and your match option would be ARE_IDENTICAL_TO , this option is nice as it lets you map all the fields you want joined.

Answer (score 0):

I received a number of suggestions, including the spatial join tool in ArcToolbox and the spatial adjustment tool.  However, the former created a new FC,which I want to avoid if possible, and the latter I didn't try, though I heard it only works on one feature at a time.

THE SOLUTION, which was the most common response:  join them based on a conflated centroid ID.  Make X and Y fields in each FC, calculate geometry of the centroid, then make a text field and calculate it as [xfield] & [yfield].  Make sure it is a string field, not numeric, or else it will just add all the numbers together and make a mess.  Then all I had to do was join them on that unique ID and calculate the various attributes.  Whew!